# Mailcow MTASTS: no policy, Tane: no TLSA(s)

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, mail-server

I have a problem with Mailcow.
I have installed it on my centos web server and sending and receiving mail seems to work fine. Since i dont want to use the web mail version of it i need some additional configuration so i can use it in other apps. I managed to send a mail from an application but it directly landed in the spam folder. Even if i added dmarc and dkim. Actually not sure what went wrong but i heard i need MTASTS. So i try to have it. Please correct me if its the wrong problem. I also tried to login via outlook and google mail. both didn't work.

This is the result i get when i test my mail domain with:
https://www.checktls.com/

[image]

this are th DNS records i added

[image]

also i created a file called mat-sts.txt with its content under
`/opt/mailcow-dockerized/data/web/.well-known`

when i restart mailcow i cant access
https://mta-sts.mail.duckpondrec.com/.well-known/mta-sts.txt

this is the nginx config for mail.duckpondrec.com

```
server {
    if ($host = mail.duckpondrec.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mail.duckpondrec.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mail.duckpondrec.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.duckpondrec.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.duckpondrec.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:30081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

any idea what i am doing wrong and why i cant send mail in a other application?
Big thanks for the help in advance!!!